# How to COUNT with given month and year only

Tags: php, date, datediff, date-difference

I have two string like below.

[image]

How do I get difference between them in PHP?

I tried code below

```
<?php echo date_diff(date_create($experience[$i]->StartWork),date_create($experience[$i]->EndWork))->format("%a days"); ?>
```

Comment: The problem described done. Where is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: what are you counting? what do mean by the "difference between them "

Comment: @ankitsuthar I edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
 <?php
 $date1 = "may 1994";
 $date2 = "august 1997";
 $diff = strtotime($date2)-strtotime($date1);
 $days = $diff / (60*60*24*1);
 echo "days :". $days;
 ?>
```

Demo : : https://eval.in/852242

Comment: only do this for  PHP < 5.3

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("may 1994"); //$experience[$i]->StartWork
$date2 = new DateTime("august 1997"); //$experience[$i]->EndWork
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);


echo "days diff = " . $interval->days ;
```